# Having trouble validating this RSS feed

Tags: xml, validation, rss

I'm going slowly insane, trying to figure out what this is failing validation.

The validator says: "not well-formed (invalid token)"

And points to the following line:

```
<link>http://www.npr.org/blogs/krulwich/2013/06/25/195521917/the-man-with-a-battery-operated-brain?ft=1&f=1007</link>
```

...which from what I can tell is entirely valid.

Please see: [http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Flinkthing.co%2Fpublic%2FWA4q1Z35%3Fm%3Drss#l110](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http://linkthing.co/public/WA4q1Z35?m=rss#l110)

Your help would be appreciated, as I'm at the end of my rope.

Comment: If you click on the help button in the validator, you will see "escaping problematic characters (< becomes &lt;, & becomes &amp;, etc.". Try to wrap your urls in CDATA section.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I didn't that could be it as there are no characters in the "failed" link that aren't used in many links that pass. That being said, I'll try CDATA and see if it works. Thank-you again.